# jQuery Drag & Drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Drag-drop-Sorting-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-html5sortable.html) plugin for Drag ,Drop and sorting list. My HTML code is like below.

```
 <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Cras justo odio</li>
       <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
       <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Morbi leo risus</li>
       <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
       <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Vestibulum at eros</li>
 </ul>
```

My JavaScript is like below

```
   <script>
            $(function () {
                $(".list-group").sortable();
            });
   </script>
```

Here is my `head` section is like below

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.sortable.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".list-group").sortable();
        });
    </script>
```

Often drag & drop is working, often not. Why it is happening like this ?

Comment: When doesn't work? It work correctly in http://jsfiddle.net/7zgansy6/

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad. You can see this   https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEICG.jpg. Thanks.

Comment: Have you another CSS/Javascript code in your page? So you should create jsfiddle contain all of them

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad. I edited my Question. Thanks.

Comment: @Muhammad, Is there any rule to drag and drop using Mouse ? Often it is working, often not.